# Adding image in the sender profile

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, html, images

Is it possible to add an image to the sender profile or the HTML code in the Marketing Cloud so that my custom logo shows in the inbox in this place instead of this grey icon? How can that be achieved?

[image]

I'd be grateful for any help!

Comment: Looks like currently there are a couple options depending on which Email Client you want it displayed in. Google Annotate, BIMI and Microsoft's Business Platform (beta). See this link for more info: https://corp.inntopia.com/how-do-i-get-my-logo-to-appear-in-emails/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, but it has nothing to do with the sender profile, instead with your template / email: https://ampscript.com/company-logo-in-gmail-using-promotions-tab/

48x48px logo

```
<!-- Custom Logo -->
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
<meta itemprop="name" content="AMPscript" />
<meta itemprop="logo" content="https://image.s7.sfmc-content.com/lib/fe9013737562047473/m/1/ampscript.png" />
</div>
```

The official SF docs:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ceb_google_promotions_tab.htm&type=5

say:

> Learn how to use a Google Promotions Tab code in Marketing Cloud Content Builder to enhance your email promotions with images, deals, expiration dates, and more.

> Create a code snippet with the sample AMPscript markup and edit the bold areas with your details. If the tab content is the same between emails that use the template, add the code snippet directly under the template  tag. If the tab content changes between emails that use the template, add a content area directly under the template  tag, then drag in your code snippet.

```
 %%[
      SET @JSONStart = Concat('<', 'script type="', 'application/ld+json"','>')
      SET @JSONEnd = Concat('<','/','script','>')
      ]%%
      %%=TreatAsContent(@JSONStart)=%%
      [{
      "@context": "https://schema.org/",
      "@type": "Organization",
      "logo": "urlforlogo.png"
      },{
      "@context": "https://schema.org/",
      "@type": "DiscountOffer",
      "description": "20% off",
      "discountCode": "PROMO",
      "availabilityStarts": "2019-01-01T08:00:00-07:00",
      "availabilityEnds": "2019-09-30T23:59:59-07:00"
      },{
      "@context": "https://schema.org/",
      "@type": "PromotionCard",
      "image": "https://urlforimage.png"
      }]
      %%=TreatAsContent(@JSONEnd)=%%
```

Comment: Hi Jonas, isn't Google part of the BIMI group that wants to add Logos in DNS records? Is this still a valid option? I only know of BIMI and trustedDialog (german speaking room), therefore this came as a surprise to me. Are there other email providers that are using this kind of implementation. I am keen to include a logo for as many email clients as possible right now ;)

Comment: This is a link-only answer and should either be a comment or you should add in information pulled from the link in to the answer in case the link URL ever changes or is removed to ensure the answer is still relevant.

Comment: Hi, I've tried this solution but it didn't work. I see that someone also left a comment that it doesn't work for them anymore. Do you think this is the only solution that there is?

Comment: @KatieCray - Google Annotate is only for when displayed in Promo tab, and yes, I have heard mixed feedback on it. Outside of that, there is the BIMI option. Outside of that and the Microsoft option for MS email clients, there really is not any other places to explore.